# Determine the sequence of functions is uniformly convergent or not.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}^{+∞}_{n=1}$ be a sequence of functions where $f_{n}(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n+x}$ where x belongs to [0,1] and n belongs to N (all natural numbers).

Determine whether the sequences of functions $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent or not.

I've found the point-wise limit is
$$
f(x)=\left \{\begin{array}{l}
1, x=1 \\
x,0<x<1\\
0, x=0 \end{array} \right.
$$

But I don't know I should choose which function to compute $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ and find the supremum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$

Comment: Perhaps you could also add a few lines to your question stating your attempts at a solution? Or, what you think you need to do to get a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convergence is uniform. Note that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac {x(1+x)} {1+n+x} \leq \frac 2 {1+n}$ for  $0<x<1$. Also, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ for $x=0$ and $x=1$. These facts imply that $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Comment: Thank you very much. But could you tell me why $\frac{x(1+x)}{1+n+x} \leq \frac{2}{1+n}$ please?

Comment: @lovemath $x(1+x) \leq (1)(2)=2$ and $1+n+x\geq 1+n$.